# What is the correct way to externally power a MKR 1010 WiFi

Tags: power, breadboard, mkr1010

I'm a little confused by the powering arrangements of the MKR 1010 WiFi. I need to power it on a breadboard from an external power supply. I will not be using a LiPo battery and I need it to work when the USB is disconnected.

Assuming there is no battery or USB connected, I think I need to apply power on the `Vin` pin (the pinout diagram on `arduino.cc` shows this as an input pin and `5V` as an output pin). However, the `5V` pin has a resettable fuse inline whereas `Vin` does not, which to me is counterintuitive.

So my questions are twofold:

1. What is the correct pin for supplying external power, and
2. What is the correct voltage to apply

Comment: https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mkr-wifi-1010 see the FAQ section

Comment: @Juraj While that does at least in part answer the question, it might have been more in the spirit of Stack Exchange to copy that FAQ section into an answer. External links tend to rot over time and are not especially helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct pin for supplying external power, and

VIN

> What is the correct voltage to apply

The bq24195 can accept between 3.9V and 17V according to the datasheet. However the power LED on the board may blow if you apply more than about 12v since it only has a 330Ω resistor with it.

---

The polyfuse on 5V is there to protect the USB's power connection incase the user makes a mistake and short circuits it. It's more for the protection of your computer's USB port than the MKR board itself.